# Only one <div> element appearing on screen

Tags: html, css, element

I am trying to make a website that has a navigation bar at the top, as well as an opening header. However, whenever I test my code, only one `<div>` element appears; the other is missing. Does anyone know why? I want my site to be similar to that of [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)'s website, with a navigation bar at the top and a large, colorful header.

Here is the code I have so far:

```css
/* Declare some variables for CSS */
:root {

    /* Website fonts */

    /*    Titles     */ --poppins:         "Poppins",         sans-serif;
    /*  Normal text  */ --source-sans-pro: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;   

    /* Colors */

    /* A nice, warm(ish) yellow |   Turbo Yellow   */
    --yellow: 255, 225, 0;

    /* A deep, near-black grey  |     Cod Grey     */
    --grey: 23, 23, 23;

    /* A dark, sharp violet     |  Electric Violet */
    --violet: 170, 0, 200;

    /* A deep, pinkish red      |     Monza Red    */
    --red: 189, 0, 57;

    /* some constant variables */
    --animation-speed: 5s

}

html, body {

    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;

}

/* Basic text setup */
p.text {

    /* Don't have the text all the way to the left */
    margin: 40px;

    /* Set a good font */
    font-family: var(--source-sans-pro);

    /*  Align text to center */
    text-align: center;

}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ANIMATED BACKGROUND */

/* Opening divider */
.opener {

    /* Align it properly */
    height:        100%;
    position:  absolute;
    top:            0px;
    right:          0px;
    left:           0px;

    /* Gradient background, slightly darkened */
    background: linear-gradient(55deg, rgba(var(--red), 0.9), rgba(var(--violet), 0.9));
    
    /* Make sue to cover the whole page */
    background-size: 200% 100%;

    /* Set a background color */
    background-color: var(--grey);

    /* Make text in this divider white -- contrasts nicely with background */
    color: white;

    /* Animate the gradient! */
    -webkit-animation: background var(--animation-speed) ease infinite;
    -moz-animation:    background var(--animation-speed) ease infinite;
    -o-animation:      background var(--animation-speed) ease infinite;
    animation:         background var(--animation-speed) ease infinite;
}

/* Gradient animation, Webkit */
@-webkit-keyframes background {

    0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;   }
    50%  { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%;   }

}

/* Gradient animation, Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes background {

    0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;   }
    50%  { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%;   }

}

/* Gradient animation, Opera */
@-o-keyframes background {

    0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;   }
    50%  { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%;   }

}

/* Gradient animation */
@keyframes background {

    0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;   }
    50%  { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%;   }

}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* Headings & titles */
.heading {

    /*  Align heading to center */
    text-align: center;

    /* Set a good font */
    font-family: var(--poppins);

    /* Make it BIG! */
    font-size: 550%;

    /* Make sure it's not too light */
    opacity: 100%;

}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* NAVIGATION BAR */

/* Naviigation bar background */
.nav-bar {

    background-color: var(--grey);
    overflow:              hidden;

}

/* Navigation bar buttons */
.nav-bar a {

    float:            left;
    display:         block;
    color:         white;
    text-align:     center;
    padding:     14px 16px;
    text-decoration:  none;
    font-size:        17px;

  }

/* Navigation bar hover stylization */
.nav-bar a :hover {

  background-color:  var(--grey);
  color:                 white;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html leng = "en">

<!-- If you're seeing this, hello! Here, you can see the inner workings of my website. -->

<head>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

    <!-- Website title -->
    <title> Website! </title>


<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

    <!-- All imports here -->

    <!-- Cool fonts from Google Fonts -->
    <link rel = "preconnect" 
            href = "https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel = "stylesheet"
            href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,500;1,500&family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,600;1,600&display=swap">

    <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" 
            type = "text/css" 
            href = "styles.css" 
            media = "screen"/>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

    <!-- Encoding -->
    <meta charset  = "utf-8">

</head>

<!-- All the text -->
<body>

    <div class = "nav-bar" 
            id = "nav-bar">

        <a #home 
            class = "active">   Home   </a>

        <a #projects>         Projects </a>

        <a #about-me>         About Me </a>

        <a #media>              Media  </a>

        <a href = "javascript:void(0);" 
            class = "icon" 
            onclick = "selection()"> <i class = "fa fa-bars"> </i> </a>

    </div>

    <div class  = "opener">

        <h1 class = "heading"> Site Title </h1>

        <p class = "text"> Some text goes here... </p>

        <p class = "text"> Some more text here... </p>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: `<a #id>` is invalid HTML. It should be `<a href="#id>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [absolutely positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute) your `.opener` element, it snapped to the edge of the screen, covering your nav:

```css
/* Declare some variables for CSS */
:root {

    /* Website fonts */

    /*    Titles     */ --poppins:         "Poppins",         sans-serif;
    /*  Normal text  */ --source-sans-pro: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;   

    /* Colors */

    /* A nice, warm(ish) yellow |   Turbo Yellow   */
    --yellow: 255, 225, 0;

    /* A deep, near-black grey  |     Cod Grey     */
    --grey: 23, 23, 23;

    /* A dark, sharp violet     |  Electric Violet */
    --violet: 170, 0, 200;

    /* A deep, pinkish red      |     Monza Red    */
    --red: 189, 0, 57;

    /* some constant variables */
    --animation-speed: 5s

}

html, body {

    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;

}

/* Basic text setup */
p.text {

    /* Don't have the text all the way to the left */
    margin: 40px;

    /* Set a good font */
    font-family: var(--source-sans-pro);

    /*  Align text to center */
    text-align: center;

}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ANIMATED BACKGROUND */

/* Opening divider */
.opener {

    /* Align it properly */
    height:        100%;
    /* position:  absolute; */
    top:            0px;
    right:          0px;
    left:           0px;

    /* Gradient background, slightly darkened */
    background: linear-gradient(55deg, rgba(var(--red), 0.9), rgba(var(--violet), 0.9));
    
    /* Make sue to cover the whole page */
    background-size: 200% 100%;

    /* Set a background color */
    background-color: var(--grey);

    /* Make text in this divider white -- contrasts nicely with background */
    color: white;

    /* Animate the gradient! */
    -webkit-animation: background var(--animation-speed) ease infinite;
    -moz-animation:    background var(--animation-speed) ease infinite;
    -o-animation:      background var(--animation-speed) ease infinite;
    animation:         background var(--animation-speed) ease infinite;
}

/* Gradient animation, Webkit */
@-webkit-keyframes background {

    0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;   }
    50%  { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%;   }

}

/* Gradient animation, Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes background {

    0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;   }
    50%  { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%;   }

}

/* Gradient animation, Opera */
@-o-keyframes background {

    0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;   }
    50%  { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%;   }

}

/* Gradient animation */
@keyframes background {

    0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;   }
    50%  { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%;   }

}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* Headings & titles */
.heading {

    /*  Align heading to center */
    text-align: center;

    /* Set a good font */
    font-family: var(--poppins);

    /* Make it BIG! */
    font-size: 550%;

    /* Make sure it's not too light */
    opacity: 100%;

}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* NAVIGATION BAR */

/* Naviigation bar background */
.nav-bar {

    background-color: var(--grey);
    overflow:              hidden;

}

/* Navigation bar buttons */
.nav-bar a {

    float:            left;
    display:         block;
    color:         black;
    text-align:     center;
    padding:     14px 16px;
    text-decoration:  none;
    font-size:        17px;

  }

/* Navigation bar hover stylization */
.topnav a :hover {

  background-color:  var(--grey);
  color:                 white;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html leng = "en">

<!-- If you're seeing this, hello! Here, you can see the inner workings of my website. -->

<head>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

    <!-- Website title -->
    <title> Website! </title>


<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

    <!-- All imports here -->

    <!-- Cool fonts from Google Fonts -->
    <link rel = "preconnect" 
            href = "https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel = "stylesheet"
            href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,500;1,500&family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,600;1,600&display=swap">

    <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" 
            type = "text/css" 
            href = "styles.css" 
            media = "screen"/>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

    <!-- Encoding -->
    <meta charset  = "utf-8">

</head>

<!-- All the text -->
<body>

    <div class = "nav-bar" 
            id = "nav-bar">

        <a #home 
            class = "active">   Home   </a>

        <a #projects>         Projects </a>

        <a #about-me>         About Me </a>

        <a #media>              Media  </a>

        <a href = "javascript:void(0);" 
            class = "icon" 
            onclick = "selection()"> <i class = "fa fa-bars"> </i> </a>

    </div>

    <div class  = "opener">

        <h1 class = "heading"> Site Title </h1>

        <p class = "text"> Some text goes here... </p>

        <p class = "text"> Some more text here... </p>

    </div>

</body>
```

I'm guessing, though, that you want the navbar floating on top of the `.opener`, so you could make it [`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#relative) and set it with a positive [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index):

```css
/* Declare some variables for CSS */
:root {

    /* Website fonts */

    /*    Titles     */ --poppins:         "Poppins",         sans-serif;
    /*  Normal text  */ --source-sans-pro: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;   

    /* Colors */

    /* A nice, warm(ish) yellow |   Turbo Yellow   */
    --yellow: 255, 225, 0;

    /* A deep, near-black grey  |     Cod Grey     */
    --grey: 23, 23, 23;

    /* A dark, sharp violet     |  Electric Violet */
    --violet: 170, 0, 200;

    /* A deep, pinkish red      |     Monza Red    */
    --red: 189, 0, 57;

    /* some constant variables */
    --animation-speed: 5s

}

html, body {

    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;

}

/* Basic text setup */
p.text {

    /* Don't have the text all the way to the left */
    margin: 40px;

    /* Set a good font */
    font-family: var(--source-sans-pro);

    /*  Align text to center */
    text-align: center;

}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ANIMATED BACKGROUND */

/* Opening divider */
.opener {

    /* Align it properly */
    height:        100%;
    position:  absolute;
    top:            0px;
    right:          0px;
    left:           0px;

    /* Gradient background, slightly darkened */
    background: linear-gradient(55deg, rgba(var(--red), 0.9), rgba(var(--violet), 0.9));
    
    /* Make sue to cover the whole page */
    background-size: 200% 100%;

    /* Set a background color */
    background-color: var(--grey);

    /* Make text in this divider white -- contrasts nicely with background */
    color: white;

    /* Animate the gradient! */
    -webkit-animation: background var(--animation-speed) ease infinite;
    -moz-animation:    background var(--animation-speed) ease infinite;
    -o-animation:      background var(--animation-speed) ease infinite;
    animation:         background var(--animation-speed) ease infinite;
}

/* Gradient animation, Webkit */
@-webkit-keyframes background {

    0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;   }
    50%  { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%;   }

}

/* Gradient animation, Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes background {

    0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;   }
    50%  { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%;   }

}

/* Gradient animation, Opera */
@-o-keyframes background {

    0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;   }
    50%  { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%;   }

}

/* Gradient animation */
@keyframes background {

    0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;   }
    50%  { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%;   }

}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* Headings & titles */
.heading {

    /*  Align heading to center */
    text-align: center;

    /* Set a good font */
    font-family: var(--poppins);

    /* Make it BIG! */
    font-size: 550%;

    /* Make sure it's not too light */
    opacity: 100%;

}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* NAVIGATION BAR */

/* Naviigation bar background */
.nav-bar {

    background-color: var(--grey);
    overflow:              hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

/* Navigation bar buttons */
.nav-bar a {

    float:            left;
    display:         block;
    color:         white;
    text-align:     center;
    padding:     14px 16px;
    text-decoration:  none;
    font-size:        17px;

  }

/* Navigation bar hover stylization */
.topnav a :hover {

  background-color:  var(--grey);
  color:                 white;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html leng = "en">

<!-- If you're seeing this, hello! Here, you can see the inner workings of my website. -->

<head>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

    <!-- Website title -->
    <title> Website! </title>


<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

    <!-- All imports here -->

    <!-- Cool fonts from Google Fonts -->
    <link rel = "preconnect" 
            href = "https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel = "stylesheet"
            href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,500;1,500&family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,600;1,600&display=swap">

    <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" 
            type = "text/css" 
            href = "styles.css" 
            media = "screen"/>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

    <!-- Encoding -->
    <meta charset  = "utf-8">

</head>

<!-- All the text -->
<body>

    <div class = "nav-bar" 
            id = "nav-bar">

        <a #home 
            class = "active">   Home   </a>

        <a #projects>         Projects </a>

        <a #about-me>         About Me </a>

        <a #media>              Media  </a>

        <a href = "javascript:void(0);" 
            class = "icon" 
            onclick = "selection()"> <i class = "fa fa-bars"> </i> </a>

    </div>

    <div class  = "opener">

        <h1 class = "heading"> Site Title </h1>

        <p class = "text"> Some text goes here... </p>

        <p class = "text"> Some more text here... </p>

    </div>

</body>
```

Also, for what it is worth, as long as you are putting a navbar at the top of your site, consider using a [`<nav>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) instead of a `div` for improved semantics and accessibility.

Comment: This works, thank you very much! I know you have already answered my question, but could you let me know if it is possible to assign a color to the nav bar, rather than having it be the same as the animated background?

Comment: Glad this worked for you! As for setting a background color, using a [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) CSS property in your `.nav-bar` CSS declaration should do the trick.  It's not working in your snippet because the value you have assigned to `--grey` is not a valid background color value-- you probably intended to use `rgb(23, 23, 23)` instead of simply `23, 23, 23`.

Answer (score 0):

just update your CSS

```
.nav-bar{
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1
}
```